# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string - SOAPClient

Tags: php, laravel, soap

I am having some issues getting a response back from a SOAP interface. The structure of the data I am trying to send to the interface is supposed to look as follows:

```
<xsd:FindServiceProviderLocationIdRequest>
     <!--You have a CHOICE of the next 2 items at this level-->
     <xsd:address>
        <xsd:streetNumber>?</xsd:streetNumber>
        <xsd:streetName>?</xsd:streetName>
        <xsd:streetType>?</xsd:streetType>
        <xsd:suburb>?</xsd:suburb>
        <xsd:state>?</xsd:state>
        <xsd:postcode>?</xsd:postcode>
     </xsd:address>
     <xsd:serviceProvider>?</xsd:serviceProvider>
  </xsd:FindServiceProviderLocationIdRequest>
```

This is how I am trying to send the address to the interface:

```
class addy extends Controller {
    var $streetNumber;
    var $streetName;
    var $streetType;
    var $suburb;
    var $state;
    var $postcode;
    function addy($a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f) {
        $this->streetNumber = $a;
        $this->streetName = $b;
        $this->streetType = $c;
        $this->suburb = $d;
        $this->state= $e;
        $this->postcode= $f;
    }
}
$address = new addy('50','Random','Street','Random City','NNN', '4000');
$soapstruct = new SoapVar($address, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, "address");
$resp = $client->findServiceProviderLocationId($soapstruct);
```

But I am still getting the stdClass error.
This is my first time exploring SOAP so I am sure there is something small I am missing.

Comment: i would add "http://soapinterop.org/xsd" as the last parameter for the soapVar, also what does findServiceProviderLocationId do and on which line the error occurs.
pls add the output of $client->echoStruct(new SoapParam($soapstruct, "inputStruct"));

Comment: It spits out a number or array of numbers that correspond to the address in the system and the error is on the last line. This is what I get from the echo:
`Function ("echoStruct") is not a valid method for this service`

Comment: maybe $client->__soapCall('findServiceProviderLocationId', array($soapstruct)) do u have a wsdl ?

Comment: I do have a WSDL and that fails with the same error

Comment: When I dd the soap structure I get the following, which doesn't seem right:
`+"enc_value": addy {#250 ▼
    +streetNumber: null
    +streetName: null
    +streetType: null
    +suburb: null
    +state: null
    +postcode: null` Shouldn't these contain the values I set prior?

Comment: i use https://github.com/wsdl2phpgenerator/wsdl2phpgenerator-cli to generate the classes and create the parameters by just creating a new class and executed $client->__soapCall('functionnamefromwsdl', array($classinstancewithValues)) this worked for all soap apis for me so far

Comment: I tried using the generator, was a step in the right direction but I am still getting the class error

Comment: How do you initialize your soap client? Can you provide some code, how the `$client` object is initialized? You should init the soap client with the trace option enabled. This ensures, that you can use `$client->__getLastRequest()` and `$client->__getLastResponse()` for having a look at the xml data you 've send and recieved. Your request is supposed to fail, because the request itself is another complex type structure and differs from address. You 're just using the `address` complex type for the request. This should end up in a soap fault.